# receiving a file from a query in python

Tags: python, syntax, subprocess, wget

I'm writing a Python script for parsing a file I receive back from a query. I have the working query command: 
wget "https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=CDK10+AND+organism:9606+AND+gene_exact:cdk10&columns=id&format=tab"

I'm trying to run the command with the subprocess.Popen method.

what is the correct syntax?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi Tal, first of all, you should show some code. You can use the [subprocess doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: Please edit your question to containt the relevant code. Check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi @Tal Welcome To Stack overflow Please Show Your Error Or Something So We Can Help You Please Add Some Details So We Can Help You Better Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Python library to perform the HTTP GET request, which is a better option

Below is the Sample code in python using requests library

```
import requests

url= "https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=CDK10+AND+organism:9606+AND+gene_exact:cdk10&columns=id&format=tab"

response = requests.get(url)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: Well, he asked about `subprocess` syntax... What if he can not use an external  dependiences?